# Python Programming Decision Structures

Tags: python

Often when I do programming and use decisions structures (along with raw input), the answer I pick is ignored and goes to the first "if" statement and displays the output for that.

In class we have to create a game using loops and decision structures. When I run the program, I keep coming across the problem of the program outputting the output for the 'if' statement instead of the answer the user picks.

For example;

```
score=0
while True:

    optionOne=raw_input("Please pick one of the options!")


    if (optionOne=="one" or "One" or "ONE"):
        print "You have succesfully sneaked out without alerting your parents!"
        print "Your current score is " + str(score)
        break
    elif (optionOne=="two" or "Two" or "TWO"):
        print "Due to stress from work, your mom does not notice your lies and allows you to leave."
        print "Your current score is " + str(score)
        break
    elif (optionOne=="three" or "Three" or "THREE"):
        print "Your mom is understanding and allows you go to the party!"
        score=score+10
        print "You get 10 additional points for being honest!"
        print "Your current score is " + str(score)
        break
```

here, despite the user choosing the second option, the output for the first "if" statement is used. I am confused what syntax error or mistake I am making for this to occur.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:
`if (optionOne=="one" or "One" or "ONE"):`

In Python an empty string(or sequence) is considered `False` while a string(or sequence with values) is considered `True`.

```
>>> bool('')
False

>>> bool('One')
True

>>>'two'=='one' or 'One' or "ONE"
'One'
```

In above comparison `'two'=='one'` is `False` but `False or 'One'` will return `'One'` which is `True`.

Implement it like this:

```
score=0
while True:

    optionOne=raw_input("Please pick one of the options!")


    if (optionOne in ["one", "One", "ONE"]):
        print "You have succesfully sneaked out without alerting your parents!"
        print "Your current score is " + str(score)
        break
    elif (optionOne in ["two", "Two", "TWO"]):
        print "Due to stress from work, your mom does not notice your lies and allows you to leave."
        print "Your current score is " + str(score)
        break
    elif (optionOne in ["three", "Three", "THREE"]):
        print "Your mom is understanding and allows you go to the party!"
        score=score+10
        print "You get 10 additional points for being honest!"
        print "Your current score is " + str(score)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do

```
if optionOne == "one" or optionOne == "One" or optionOne == "ONE":
```

or shorter - converting text to lower case

```
optionOne = optionOne.lower()

if optionOne == "one":
    # ...
elif optionOne == "two":
    # ...
```

If you have different words then you can use `in`

```
optionOne = optionOne.lower()

if optionOne in ("one", "1"):
    # ...
elif optionOne in ("two", "2"):
    # ...
```

---

BTW: Code

```
if optionOne=="one" or "One" or "ONE":
```

is treated as

```
if (optionOne == "one") or ("One") or ("ONE")
```

and `"One"` (and `"ONE"`) is treated as `True` so you have

```
if (optionOne == "one") or True or True:
```

which always is `True`